# Algorithm for Choosing Numbers with the Maximum/Minimum Sum from a Sequence

Tags: optimization, algorithms, dynamic-programming

These are two related questions that I found as part of an informatics competition; i.e. a competition in which the aim is to write a computer program that outputs what is asked.

> Q1. Given a finite sequence of numbers (the input), we move across it left to right and at each step, we can either choose the current number or exclude it. However, we cannot *exclude* three numbers in a row. Find the *minimum* possible sum of such a selection.
>
> Q2. Given a finite sequence of numbers (the input), we move across it left to right and at each step, we can either choose the current number or exclude it. However, we cannot *choose* three numbers in a row. Find the *maximum* possible sum of such a selection.

Of course, we can always brute-force this by looking at all possible selections and summing them, but I found a better way of solving the first question. We start by choosing the minimum among the first three elements, and then choose the minimum of the next three from the current position. But if we choose, say, the second element, and then we choose the first element after that (in the next step), we combine those two into a single step, omitting the second element.

My first question is: does this approach give the correct answer? And my second question is: is there a similar better way of solving the second question?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer your first question after fiddling around with this problem a little in C#.
What I found is, that your approach fails to give the minimum possible sum, when the length of the sequence is particularly short ( between 10 and 200 integers ).
One algorithm that some times beats yours for short sequences is to just pick every third item.

You can find the code that i've used to test this [here](http://pastebin.com/WevXufsF) 
Although most of the time it will give the best result, in about 1/3 of the test cases it failed to do so.

So my guess for your second question is that there is a better way to solve this, although i can't tell you the algorithm for it. What I'm thinking is that you will have to optimize the picks in a way, such that for the last picked number the amount of remaining numbers in the sequence is 2 or 1.

Comment: This this doesn't *completely* answer the question, but only *comments* on the OP's suggested approach, this might be better suited as a comment.

Comment: @PatrickLouis Can you explain how/why my algorithm does not work with 'short' sequences? In what types of cases does it fail? Also, 'pick every third item' is definitely not going to give the minimum possible answer for a lot of sequences.

Comment: After I've put a little more thought into it I think it might not necessarily be the length of the sequence that makes your algorithm fail but rather if the sequence is (partially) sorted. Assume it contains a subsequence, that is sorted from small to big.  your algorithm will pick the first number of that subsequence because its the smallest, next it will pick the second number of the sequence, because it's the smallest of the next 3 and so on. This will result in summing up the whole subsequence, whereas picking every 3rd number will give you a smaller sum.

Comment: Quoting from my original post: "But if we choose, say, the second element, and then we choose the first element after that (in the next step), we combine those two into a single step, omitting the second element." This ensures that I eventually end up selecting the third element in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to both questions: Use dynamic programming!

Consider the following algorithm to answer $Q1$ where we assume the input is stored in an array $a$ of length $n$: (note that I use c++ like syntax and assume that $n \geq 2$)

```
int dp[n + 1];
dp[0] = 0;
dp[1] = a[0];
dp[2] = min(dp[0], dp[1]) + a[1];
for(int i = 3; i < n + 1; i++){
   dp[i] = min(dp[i - 3], dp[i - 2], dp[i - 1]) + a[i - 1];
}
int result = min(dp[n], dp[n - 1], dp[n - 2]);
```

The meaning of the $i$-th entry of the $dp$ table is the following:

$dp[i] = k \iff$ $k$ is the minimum sum reachable under your constraints for the first $i$ numbers of the input given that we cannot exclude element $i$

For example for the first $0$ elements of the input we know that the answer must be $0$. Hence $dp[0] = 0$. For the first $1$ elements of the input we know that the answer must be $0$. But under the additional constraint that we must include the first element for the $dp$ entry we get that $dp[1] = a[0]$. For the first $2$ elements of the input we know that the answer must be $0$. But under the condition that we must include the first element for the $dp$ entry we get that $dp[2] = a[1]$ (Note that in the code I overcomplicated this for the sake of seeing the pattern). For the first $3$ elements of the input we know that the answer must be the minimum of $a[0], a[1], a[2]$. But given that the third element must be included we get $dp[3] = a[2]$. And so on...

In order to answer $Q2$ you can use a very similar approach: Use a $dp$-table and try to answer the following question: If you knew what the solution is for the first $i$ entries for all $i < k$, how can you find the solution for the first $k$ entries?